# Do we still need reference tags at the top of an Angular2 component file?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and have installed Typings. I followed the steps in the [Angular2 quickstart](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/). In it, the component.ts file does not have a reference tag anymore.

What has changed so that we don't use reference now?

I am getting these types of build errors without them. I think there's something wrong in my setup but I don't know what it is.

```
"Property '____' does not exist on type '____'" (TS2339)
"Cannot find name '____'" (TS2304) errors.
```

This is what I have for my web project file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>3775534b-d08c-45f2-8d5a-4a4f6e91edb9</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>MyProject</RootNamespace>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">..\..\artifacts\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">..\..\artifacts\bin\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</OutputPath>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="FixTsBuildConfiguration" BeforeTargets="CompileTypeScript" >
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations.Replace("--moduleResolution NodeJs", "--moduleResolution node"))</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
   </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="bower.json" />
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include=".bowerrc" />
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="package.json" />
    <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="wwwroot\bower_components\" />
    <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="wwwroot\node_modules\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
</Project>
```

UPDATE 1

This is what I have for tsconfig.json. It's the same as what's in the Angular2 quickstart.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

UPDATE 2

I found out that setting up Angular2 in Visual Studio 2015 requires another approach. I followed the steps in [Starting Angular 2 in ASP.NET 5 with TypeScript using Visual Studio 2015](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/) and I didn't get any build issues anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> What has changed so that we don't use reference now?

You never need reference tags if you are using something else (like tsconfig.json) to manage your compilation context: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html

Comment: If that's the case, why am I still getting errors if I have the same config as the one being referred to in the Angular2 quickstart? (Please see my update for the tsconfig.json.) I think there may be something wrong with my web project file but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues.  I added the following reference tag to my `app/main.ts` (or wherever you bootstrap the app from).  I did not have to add reference tags to all files.

```
///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me because it gives me duplicate identifier errors when I do that.

Comment: Have you tried creating the project and building outside of Visual Studio?